# Chkdsk in Windows 7

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has Microsoft improved Scandisk, CHKDSK and Defrag in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/210680/has-microsoft-improved-scandisk-chkdsk-and-defrag-in-windows-7)

Has chkdsk been updated in Windows 7?  Is there any difference between running chkdsk on Windows 7 vs. running it on Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, the CHKDSK on Windows 7 supports the newer features of NTFS, and also has a bad block rescan feature. What this does is re-check every sector, including those marked as bad, and see if they are still bad. This is important if you imaged a bad hard drive over with bad blocks already on it; once Windows 7 (or Vista) sees this bad block, it doesn't write over it. With the `/b` option, it rechecks that and reclaims the space as available for you

Answer (score 2):

have not found anything different in my usage, but apparently there are some very minor differences just because windows7 is much newer, as you can see here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62912a3c-d2cc-4ef6-9679-43709a286035